# VS Code Editor font size issue

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor, font-size

There is a bug on VS Code Editor which makes font size shrink to the smallest on pressing Ctrl key. I don't know if others are having it too. Often I have to do actions using shortcut keys which involves pressing Ctrl key, which upon pressing makes the font size of the editor slowly shrink to the smallest in a couple of milliseconds.

1. The OS is Windows 10 : [Version 10.0.19042.928]
2. VS Code Version: 1.55.2 (system setup)
3. Electron: 11.3.0
4. Chrome: 87.0.4280.141
5. Node.js: 12.18.3
6. The device is Asus TUF Gaming A15.

Any good ideas will be really helpful ....

Comment: How this is related to javascript ?

Comment: Currently I am working with javascript  in it

Answer (score 0):

Check your keyboard setting, see if you have unexpectedly bind `ctrl` key to zoom view.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to make a fresh installation of VsCode?

For doing a fresh installation :

1. Uninstall VsCode.
2. Pres <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.
3. Type `%appdata%` and press enter.
4. Remove the folder named `Code`.
5. Install VsCode.

I hope this fix your problem.